# Capitalization of Numbered Nouns

Tags: capitalization

I am having issues with capitalization of numbered nouns. For example, if I want to say, "Please finish this assignment by week 8." should I capitalize Week or use lower case? For page and line, that's straightforward, and we should use lower case. But I've seen discussion about chapter, and some scholars say we should capitalize Chapter when numbers are attached after, for example, in Chapter 5,.... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

From [ESL Library](https://blog.esllibrary.com/2014/10/09/the-capitalization-of-certain-terms-exercise-page-chapter-unit-paragraph-line):

"The general rule of thumb is that if the word is (or could act as) a heading, capitalize it. If not, then don’t. (Before we look at these words in more detail, I should also mention that there is no absolute right or wrong here. The most important thing is to be consistent.)"

So, if you're referring to a syllabus that is broken down by week, and Week 1, Week 2, etc. act as headings or titles for that section of the syllabus, then this rule would seem to hold, and capitalization seems appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense.